# Parsing XML special characters using PHP

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I'm pulling information from an XML document using PHP and echoing it to a page. In the XMl document there are special characters like Éamon for example. And when I echo these characters using PHP it looks like Ã‰amon.

Can anyone tell me how I can trans-code these characters so they parse normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have the browser do it for you. In the header, specify that your character set is utf-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Do this *before* you output anything else to the browser. Now the browser will correctly decode the special characters.

Comment: Ah crap! Yeah, I knew it was something simple. Completely forgot that header.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I actually thought I had that in which is why I was confused. Then I checked and realised it was missing. Hurray for stupid mistakes!

Comment: You have to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer. You obviously haven't asked many questions, lol.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```